# How do I set the dotnet propertygrid modal editor location?

Tags: .net, propertygrid

I had hoped that IWindowsFormsEditorService.ShowDialog would pick an appropriate location for me but it doesn't.  I would like the form to open in the vicinity of the propertygrid item and not on the other side of the screen. Its location just seems to be fixed relative to the screen (and independant of the form Location property) and my attempts to get a more appropriate location seem hacky and unnecessarily complicated.
I assume there is a recommended way to do this but I can't find it.

Comment: You can define the form's StartPosition to FormStartPosition.CenterParent or Manual and then set Location

Comment: That does it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the form's StartPosition to FormStartPosition.CenterParent or Manual and then set Location